# Measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis

Show the following. E is measurable $\Longleftrightarrow$ For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a closed set $F \subset E$ such that $m^*(E) - m^*(F) < \epsilon$

Here is my attempt:

$"\leq"$

Consider $E$ is measurable.
For each natural number $k$, choose an closed set $F_k$ that is included in $E$ and for which $m^*(E - F_k) <\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$
So far we have $E$ is measurable, $F_k$ (by choosing them closed) are measurable. Apply excision property $\Rightarrow$
  $m^*(E) - m^*(F_k)=  m^*(E - F_k) < \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$

Define $F = \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty F_k.$
Then $F$ is a $F_\sigma$ set therefore measurable and included in $E$.
Since $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty F_k \subseteq E$ and using excision property $\Rightarrow$
 $m^*(E - F) = m^*(E) - m^*(F)=  m^*(E) - m^*(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty F_k)$

and i am stuck here

Comment: You need to prove that m* is inner regular. Use expanding intervals and the def of the outer measure

Comment: Are you sure the set has to be closed and not just a $F_\sigma$. Don't forget form topology that the infinite union of closed sets need not be closed.

Comment: I am sure about closed part

Comment: I read about inner measure in other books but we have not defined it, the only measure we defined so far is outer measure. We prove this theorem Let E be any set of real numbers. Then each of the following four assertions is equivalent to the measurability of E
For each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a closed set F contained in E for which $m^* (E - F) < \epsilon$.
There is an $F_\sigma$ set F contained in E for which $m^*( E - F) = 0$.

Comment: Here is how i proved $"\leq"$ but i am not sure. $E$ is measurable.
For each natural number $k$, choose an closed set $F_k$ that is included in $E$ and for which $m^*(E - F_k) <\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$
$F_k$ are measurable. Apply excision property $\Rightarrow$
  $m^*(E) - m^*(F_k)=  m^*(E - F_k) < \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$
  
$F = \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty F_k.$
Since $F = \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty F_k \subseteq E$ and using excision property $\Rightarrow$,
 $m^*(E - F) = m^*(E) - m^*(F) \leq m^*(E - F_k) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$
 $ m^*(E) - m^*(F) \leq \epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

You are proving that if $E$ is measurable, then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a closed set $F \subset E$ satisfying $m^*(E) - m^*(F) < \epsilon$.

Your first step is to choose $F_k \subset E$ satisfying $m^*(E\setminus F_k) < \epsilon/2^k$. How do you know this can be done? If it can, take $k=0$ to find $F_0$ satisfying $m^*(E) - m^*(F_0) < \epsilon$ provided that $m^*(E) < \infty$. You are essentially begging the question: assuming what you need to prove.

Your original statment says nothing about $F_\sigma$ sets. Did you state the problem wrong?

Comment: I choose $F_k$ based on the following Theorem:  Let E be any set of real numbers. Then each of the following assertions is equivalent to the measurability of E.
(1) $E$ is measurable
(2) For each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a closed set $F$ contained in E for which $m^* (E - F) < \epsilon$.
(3) There is an $F_\sigma$ set F contained in E for which $m^*( E - F) = 0$. The problem is correct. Because $F_K$ are closed a union of closed sets is a $F_\sigma$